# R Tidysynth problem with generate_control ()

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am having a problem with tidysynth. I keep getting the message "Error in aux_gen_pred(data = ., time_window = time_window, ...) : NA generated in specified predictors. Consider using `rm.na= TRUE` in aggregation function or specifying a larger/different time window". Here is my code:

```
crime_out <-
 
 SCMFinal %>%
 
 # initial the synthetic control object
 synthetic_control(outcome = homicidekm2, # outcome
                   unit = neghborhood_code, # unit index in the panel data
                   time = year, # time index in the panel data
                   i_unit = "1314", # unit where the intervention occurred
                   i_time = 2012, # time period when the intervention occurred
                   generate_placebos=T # generate placebo synthetic controls (for inference)
 ) %>%
 
 # Generate the aggregate predictors used to fit the weights
 
 #Average bulgary per km2 2003-2012
 generate_predictor(time_window = 2003:2012,
                    bulgarlykm2_p = mean(bulgarlykm2, na.rm = T)) %>%
 
 # average strata 2009-2012
 #average householdincome 2009-2012
 generate_predictor(time_window = 2009:2012,
                    strata_p = mean( strata, na.rm = T),
                    average_income_p = mean(average_income, na.rm = T)) %>%
 
 # Lagged homicide 
 generate_predictor(time_window = 2007,
                    homicidekm2_2009 = homicidekm2) %>%
 generate_predictor(time_window = 2009,
                    homicidekm2_2010 = homicidekm2) %>%
 generate_predictor(time_window = 2011,
                    homicidekm2_2011 = homicidekm2) %>%
 
 
 # Generate the fitted weights for the synthetic control
 generate_weights(optimization_window = 2003:2012, # time to use in the optimization task
                  margin_ipop = .02,sigf_ipop = 7,bound_ipop = 6 # optimizer options
 ) %>%
 
 # Generate the synthetic control
 generate_control ()
 
 #Plotting trends
 crime_out %>% plot_trends(time_window = 2003:2020)
```

I keep getting the error

```
generate_control ()
Error in aux_gen_pred(data = ., time_window = time_window, ...) : 
  NA generated in specified predictors. Consider using `rm.na= TRUE` in aggregation function or specifying a larger/different time window
```

This is the structure of my data:

```
> dput(head(SCMFinal))
structure(list(year = structure(c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008), label = "Year", format.stata = "%8.0g"), neighborhood = structure(c("Santo Domingo Savio 1", 
"Santo Domingo Savio 1", "Santo Domingo Savio 1", "Santo Domingo Savio 1", 
"Santo Domingo Savio 1", "Santo Domingo Savio 1"), format.stata = "%36s"), 
    neghborhood_code = structure(c("101", "101", "101", "101", 
    "101", "101"), label = "Neighborhood code", format.stata = "%9s"), 
    comuna = structure(c("", "", "", "", "", ""), label = "Comuna", format.stata = "%25s"), 
    comuna_code = structure(c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), format.stata = "%9s"), 
    homicides = structure(c(12, 2, 4, 3, 9, 5), label = "Number of homicides", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    bulgarly = structure(c(NA, 12, 4, 2, 2, 16), label = "Bulgarly", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    homicidekm2 = structure(c(2.13809580600355e-05, 3.56349301000591e-06, 
    7.12698602001183e-06, 5.34523951500887e-06, 1.60357194545213e-05, 
    8.90873252501478e-06), format.stata = "%9.0g"), bulgarlykm2 = structure(c(NA, 
    2.13809580600355e-05, 7.12698602001183e-06, 3.56349301000591e-06, 
    3.56349301000591e-06, 2.85079440800473e-05), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    average_income = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), label = "Average_income", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    strata = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), label = "Strata", format.stata = "%8.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```